# C++ fill() vs. uninitialized_fill()

Tags: c++

Hi I am a beginner and I want to know the difference between container's fill() and uninitialized_fill(). I did a quick search on Google but not get good answer. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fill()` assigns values (using the assignment operator) to already constructed objects. `uninitialized_fill()` constructs objects (using the copy constructor) in raw uninitialized memory.